# pysftp "paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed."

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pem, pysftp

I have access to an SFTP server using username and a ppk file. All information I have are

- host
- username
- ppk priveate key file
- the password for decrypting the ppk file

There is no server password. The password is for ppk file decryption only.

If I user Filezilla, it connects to the server fine.

Now, I would like to use python to connect to the same server. It seems `pysftp` which is an wrapper on `paramiko` is only supporting pem format and not ppk keys. I used `putty gen` for this conversion. It seem that `RSA` is not acceptable so I used `DSA` for this conversion. Provided the ppk file and its password and generated a pem private key file.

Now, following this code:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
srv = pysftp.Connection(host=sftp_host, username=sftp_user, private_key='auth.pem', cnopts=cnopts)
```

After a few seconds, I receive this error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

What would you advise?

**Notes:**

- I have tried many stackoverflow answers and did not have any success. Therefore, please avoid linking this question to another random question with similar title. Instead please suggest a solution and wait for my feedback on why it does not work me.
- I use a private key file. Please avoid referring me to the questions that use username/password for SFTP.
- Please avoid referring me to the questions for `SSH` because I do not know how to put it in `SFTP` context.
- This is about `pysftp` please do not suggest the options of `paramiko`. They do not work on a `pysftp` function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could eventually fix the problem. This was by lots of efforts plus the hints from user @martin-prikryl .

I share my solution code for others who will face with this problem in future.

The point is that there is a bug in the python library and you need to get around it by `disabled_algorithms` . I could not find such an option in `pysftp` so I migrated the code entirely to pure `paramiko`.

```
import paramiko
import io

with open('the_private_key.pem', 'r') as fh:
    keydata = fh.read()
keyfile = io.StringIO(keydata)
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfile)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(sftp_host, username=sftp_user, pkey=mykey, look_for_keys=False, disabled_algorithms=dict(pubkeys=["rsa-sha2-512", "rsa-sha2-256"]))
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
file_list = sftp.listdir()
```

.